# Почему цикл работает неправильно?

Tags: java, scanner

Почему-то когда вводишь сначала некорректный `int` (например `-5`), а потом корректный (например, `5`), то программа не выведет `5` и сделает это, только если ещё раз ввести данное значение. По идее, программа после ввода корректного значения (`int` от `1` до `10`) должна сразу вывести в консоль это число.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int correctNumber = 1;
        System.out.println("Введите число от 1 до 10:");
        while (!scanner.hasNextInt() || !isCorrectNumber(correctNumber = scanner.nextInt())) {
            System.out.println("Нужно ввести целое число со значением не менее 1 и не более 10!");
            scanner.next();
        }
        System.out.println(correctNumber);
        
    }

    static boolean isCorrectNumber(int n) {
        return n >= 1 && n <= 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: этот код даже не запускается

Comment: прошу прощения, подправила

Answer (score 2, accepted):

метод `nextInt()` считывает число
и при вводе числа и последующем нажатии enter перевод строки `"\n"` остаётся,
измените `scanner.next();`
на `scanner.nextLine();`

по той же аналогии работает метод `flush()`  он сбрасывает содержимое буфера в выходной поток и очищает его. это вам понадобиться когда потоки ввода вывода (io / nio) будете осваивать.

Comment: спасибо за комментарий!

Comment: пожалуйста, удачи в начинаниях

Answer (score 3):

Уберите вызов метода `Scanner#next`

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int correctNumber;
        System.out.println("Введите число от 1 до 10:");
        while (!scanner.hasNextInt() || !isCorrectNumber(correctNumber = scanner.nextInt()))
            System.out.println("Нужно ввести целое число со значением не менее 1 и не более 10!");
        System.out.println(correctNumber);
```